# Why dont my variables within a delayedexpansion for loop stay set? (Command Prompt / cmd.exe)

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, scripting, command-prompt

Why do my variables in the delayedexpansion loop script below not stay set?

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set DB_LIST=(DB1 DB2)
for %%i in %DB_LIST% do (

    set DATABASENAME=%%i
    echo -- Backing Up Database %DATABASENAME% -- 
    set DATESTAMP=%DATE:~-4%.%DATE:~3,2%.%DATE:~0,2%
    set BACKUPFILENAME=F:\Backups\ScheduledBackups\%DATABASENAME%-%DATESTAMP%.bak
    echo.
    sqlcmd -E -S LiveDB2 -d master -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [%DATABASENAME%] TO DISK = '%BACKUPFILENAME%' WITH DESCRIPTION = 'Full backup [%DATABASENAME%]', CHECKSUM, INIT, COMPRESSION, STATS"
)
endlocal
pause
```

I get an command that tries to execute with `BACKUP DATABASE DB1 TO DISK = ''`

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, UK Date reversal (DDMMYYYY > YYYYMMDD), so it might not show %DATESTAMP% properly on your PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are trying to expand your variables using percentage sign instead of exclamation mark. You must always use exclamation marks within `for` loops when Delayed expansion is enabled.

Try this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set DB_LIST=(DB1 DB2) 
for %%i in %DB_LIST% do (

set DATABASENAME=%%i
echo -- Backing Up Database !DATABASENAME! -- 
set DATESTAMP=%DATE:~-4%.%DATE:~3,2%.%DATE:~0,2%
set BACKUPFILENAME=F:\Backups\ScheduledBackups\!DATABASENAME!-!DATESTAMP!.bak
echo.
sqlcmd -E -S LiveDB2 -d master -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [!DATABASENAME!] TO     DISK = '!BACKUPFILENAME!' WITH DESCRIPTION = 'Full backup [!DATABASENAME!]', 

CHECKSUM, INIT, COMPRESSION, STATS")
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: Not always when *enabled*, just when delayed expansion is *needed*.  For example, `%CD%` would still work (unless he changes directory within the parenthetical code block and needs the new value of `!CD!`, of course).